# Replace the folder with file Provisioner terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to update the folder placed on ec2 by terraform file provisioner. If you are applying this for the first time it works fine but for the second time when I apply terraform apply it does not reflect the new changes to the copied folder. Any help would be appreciated

```
resource "null_resource" "code" {
  depends_on = [local_file.host_file]

  triggers = {
    always_run = timestamp()
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "../src"
    destination = "/home/ec2-user/src/"

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      host        = aws_instance.bastion.public_ip
      user        = "ec2-user"
      private_key = file("/tmp/keys/ec2-key")
      insecure    = true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So it always runs but doesn't copy over the new files?

Comment: Yes it runs but doesn't copies new changes

Comment: So if you run `terraform plan` it says there are no changes to make?

Comment: It delete the null resources and recreates it but there new changes are not reflected

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Nope it is not working

Comment: @user16133873 why not?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is expected and is by design. There's currently an [open issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/6065) for this.

This [post](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/6065#issuecomment-281347100) however has a good workaround that you can use to solve the problem.